# How do I fix the unreachable statement?

Tags: java

I tried reading about this and I can't find the real problem. I'm new to java and it's my first time that I've encountered this problem. I tried putting the counter inside main method and outside of it and it still says unreachable statement.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Harrylist{
static Random Userinput = new Random();
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String cancellor;
static int counter = 0;
static int integer = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Guessing game! please enter a total number of guesses");
  int y = input.nextInt();
  int[][] GuessingGame = new int[2][];
  GuessingGame[0] = new int[y];
  GuessingGame[1] = new int[y];
 //AI inputs
 for(int i = integer; i < y; i++){
    GuessingGame[1][i] = Userinput.nextInt(50);
    //System.out.println(GuessingGame[1][i]);
    //User inputs
    System.out.println("Please enter a number within the range of 50");
     cancellor = input.nextLine();
     GuessingGame[0][i] = input.nextInt();
     for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
       if(GuessingGame[0][integer] == GuessingGame[1][j]){
         System.out.println("Correct!");
         break;
         counter++;
       }
```

Comment: move `counter++` above the `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put anything after `break` statement because it break your loop. `counter++`  will never be reached. Use this:

```java
counter++;
break;
```

instead this:

```java
 break;
 counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

the `break` keyword causes your code to interrupt and exit out of the loop. Therefore everything insite of the `if(GuessingGame[0][integer] == GuessingGame[1][j])` condition and after the `break` will not be reached. To fix this you just need to make sure that the break statement is the last thing in its block of code.